# Why are shaders and programs stored as integers in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, integer, shader

I'm following the "OpenGL Superbible" book and I can't help but notice that when we create a shader and create the program that we attach the shaders to, we store them as GLuint which are unsigned integers.

Why are they stored as numbers? What does the value of the number mean?

example:

```
GLuint vertex_shader;
GLuint fragment_shader;
GLuint program;

// Create and compile vertex shader
vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

// Create program, attach shaders to it, and link it
program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
glLinkProgram(program);
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! I'm familiar with handles because of the Win32 API. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These integers are *handles*.This is a common idiom used by many APIs, used to hide resource access through an opaque level of indirection. OpenGL is effectively preventing you from accessing what lies behind the handle without using the API calls.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)):

> In computer programming, a handle is an abstract reference to a resource. [...] Resource handles can be opaque identifiers, in which case they are often integer numbers, or they can be pointers that allow access to further information.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the number means nothing, with the exception of `0`, which means "no object".

These values are generated by the driver when you make `glGen*()` or `glCreate*()` type calls. They are opaque references to the objects. You can imagine the driver maintaining a mapping between these numbers and the corresponding internal objects. Every time you pass in the number as the argument to an API call, e.g. `glBind*()`, the driver will look up the number, and map it back to the corresponding internal object.

Semantically, this is very much like a pointer in C/C++. When you allocate memory, you get a pointer. And you can use this pointer to reference the memory you allocated. Except, in the case of OpenGL, you don't get a raw memory address, but an opaque representation to reference the object.

The same concept is used in other APIs. For example, Windows (Win32) extensively uses opaque object references, which they call "handles".

Now you might wonder why OpenGL does not simply use pointers instead of these object ids. This is just my personal take, but I believe the main motivation is that OpenGL was designed as a client/server API, where rendering can happen on a different machine than the one running the application. If the API stream has to be packaged and sent over a network, using pointers to reference objects does not work easily. Using opaque ids is much cleaner in that case.

BTW, in official OpenGL terminology, these values are mostly called "names". Which I always found a bit misleading, because most people think of strings when they hear "name". I mostly call them "ids" myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Really cleared some things up!